# Conflict between matplotlib and pandas

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

When I run the following code below I get the below error message. The error does not occur when I comment the "pd.read_csv" line. So it seems there is a conflict between matplotlib (3.5.1) and pandas (1.4.1) but no clue what it could be. I use Pycharm Community 2021.3.2. Any ideas?

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
    
f = open("mycsv.csv", "w")
f.write("0,1,2,3,4\n1,4,2,5,3")
f.close()
pd.read_csv("mycsv.csv",sep=",")  # Commenting this line removes the error
    
data = [[0, 1, 2, 3, 4], [1, 4, 2, 5, 3]]
    
plt.plot( data[0], data[1])
plt.show()
```

Error message:

```
C:\Users\woute\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\python.exe "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition 2021.3.2\plugins\python-ce\helpers\pydev\pydevd.py" --multiproc --qt-support=auto --client 127.0.0.1 --port 55165 --file C:/Users/woute/Documents/GitHub/GolfSwing/PoseDemoWebcam/Test.py
Connected to pydev debugger (build 213.6777.50)
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\woute\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\getlimits.py", line 459, in __new__
    dtype = numeric.dtype(dtype)
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable
During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\woute\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1921, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "C:\Users\woute\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 839, in callit
    func(*args)
  File "C:\Users\woute\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\backends\_backend_tk.py", line 251, in idle_draw
    self.draw()
  File "C:\Users\woute\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\backends\backend_tkagg.py", line 9, in draw
    super().draw()
  File "C:\Users\woute\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\backends\backend_agg.py", line 436, in draw
    self.figure.draw(self.renderer)
  File "C:\Users\woute\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\artist.py", line 73, in draw_wrapper
    result = draw(artist, renderer, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\woute\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\artist.py", line 50, in draw_wrapper
    return draw(artist, renderer)
  File "C:\Users\woute\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\figure.py", line 2810, in draw
    mimage._draw_list_compositing_images(
  File "C:\Users\woute\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\image.py", line 132, in _draw_list_compositing_images
    a.draw(renderer)
  File "C:\Users\woute\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\artist.py", line 50, in draw_wrapper
    return draw(artist, renderer)
  File "C:\Users\woute\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\axes\_base.py", line 3020, in draw
    self._unstale_viewLim()
  File "C:\Users\woute\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\axes\_base.py", line 776, in _unstale_viewLim
    self.autoscale_view(**{f"scale{name}": scale
  File "C:\Users\woute\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\axes\_base.py", line 2932, in autoscale_view
    handle_single_axis(
  File "C:\Users\woute\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\axes\_base.py", line 2895, in handle_single_axis
    x0, x1 = locator.nonsingular(x0, x1)
  File "C:\Users\woute\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\ticker.py", line 1654, in nonsingular
    return mtransforms.nonsingular(v0, v1, expander=.05)
  File "C:\Users\woute\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\transforms.py", line 2880, in nonsingular
    if maxabsvalue < (1e6 / tiny) * np.finfo(float).tiny:
  File "C:\Users\woute\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\getlimits.py", line 462, in __new__
    dtype = numeric.dtype(type(dtype))
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable
```

Comment: I think you have to read the csv file into some variable i.e df = pd.read_csv("mycsv.csv",sep=",")

Comment: I cannot reproduce this problem (matplotlib 3.5.1, pandas 1.3.5, Python 3.8). Also not after upgrade to pandas 1.4.1

Comment: I don't think it's a problem of compatibility between pandas and matplotlib, also because here you are not plotting a dataframe with matplotlib, but just two lists  from a list (`data`). There must be a problem in your csv file. The error seems to start with `tkinter` module, but in the code you provided you don't use this module. Are you sure this error comes from exactly the code you posted?

Comment: I got no problem with this code. Tested on (Python3.10, Pandas Version 1.4.1, Matplotlib version: 3.5.1)

Comment: Did you check the created csv file? Does it look as expected? Are you sure the program has writing permissions in the folder where it is running? Also note that a csv file normally expects a header row and a newline after the last row.

Comment: The problem seems to be inside numpy. Does numpy work normally? Maybe there is an installation issue? E.g 32 bit vs 64 bit.

Comment: This seems to be a known problem for which (apparently) there is no solution yet. For me it was solved by downgrading to Python 3.8. Thx all for the feedback.